# Spring Boot - Unable to override RabbitMQ properties

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-boot

I've faced an issue with configuring RabbitMQ with Spring Boot.

I need to override host value for my application. I use JavaConfig approach. I use auto configuration feature as well.

So I put `spring.rabbitmq.host=myhost.com` property into `application.properties` but RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory` still created with localhost value.

**UPDATE1:** Seems like my embedded Tomcat instance doesn't pick up updates in property files. I've added some custom property and Spring can't resolve the placeholder for it.
I run my application in IntellijIdea 14 as a common java app. 
All class changes are picked up by IntellijIdea&Tomcat but all resources folder content is not.

Is this IntellijIdea 14 related issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also have "spring.rabbitmq.addresses"? Or did you create a bean of type `RabbitProperties`?

Comment: @DaveSyer, No, I don't have `spring.rabbitmq.addresses`. Should I? No, I didn't create `RabbitProperties` bean. I've debugged `RabbitAutoConfiguration` class and `RabbitProperties` comes there with `localhost` value.

Comment: Where is your application.properties file? Are any other properties that are configured in it being picked up?

Comment: I put my application.properties into resources/config/application.properties. I don't have any other property file. BTW, this file works good and I'm able to retrieve my custom properties and override server.port property. Also I can override RabbitMQ in command line arguments but not in properties file.

Answer (score 1):

If you do that from test-case, be sure to use:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

For the test class.

I think the name of the `initializer` should say for itself.

Comment: Thanks for this trick, but unfortunately I'm trying to run Spring Boot application not test-case.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved. There was issue with IntellijIdea 14 & 13 Gradle project setup/files compatibility. So Re-Import of the project is a solution.